# Parsing huge (~100mb) kml (xml) file taking *hours* without any sign of actual parsing

Tags: ruby, xml, timeout, kml, large-data

I'm currently trying to parse a very large kml (xml) file with ruby (Nokogiri) and am having a little bit of trouble.

The parsing code is good, in fact I'll share it just for the heck of it, even though this code doesn't have much to do with my problem:

```
geofactory = RGeo::Geographic.projected_factory(:projection_proj4 => "+proj=lcc +lat_1=34.83333333333334 +lat_2=32.5 +lat_0=31.83333333333333 +lon_0=-81 +x_0=609600 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +to_meter=0.3048 +no_defs", :projection_srid => 3361)
f = File.open("horry_parcels.kml")
kmldoc = Nokogiri::XML(f)

kmldoc.css("//Placemark").each_with_index do |placemark, i|
      puts i
      tds = Nokogiri::HTML(placemark.search("//description").children[0].to_html).search("tr > td")
      h = HorryParcel.new
      h.owner_name = tds.shift.text
      tds.shift
      tds.each_slice(2) do |k, v|
        col = k.text.downcase
        eval("h.#{col} = v.text")
      end
      coords = kmldoc.search("//MultiGeometry")[i].text.gsub("\n", "").gsub("\t", "").split(",0 ").map {|x| x.split(",")}
      points = coords.map { |lon, lat| geofactory.parse_wkt("POINT (#{lon} #{lat})") }
      geo_shape = geofactory.polygon(geofactory.linear_ring(points))
      proj_shape = geo_shape.projection
      h.geo_shape = geo_shape
      h.proj_shape = proj_shape
      h.save
    end
```

Anyway, I've tested this code with a much, much smaller sample of kml and it works.

However, when I load the real thing, ruby simply waits, as if it is processing something. This "processing", however, has now spanned several hours while I've been doing other things. As you might have noticed, I have a counter (`each_with_index`) on the array of Placemarks and during this multi-hour period, not a single `i` value has been `put` to the command line. Oddly enough it hasn't timed out yet, but even if this works there has got to be a better way to do this thing.

I know I could open up the KML file in Google Earth (Google Earth Pro here) and save the data in smaller, more manageable kml files, but the way things appear to be set up, this would be a very manual, unprofessional process.

Here's a sample of the kml (w/ just one placemark) if that helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>justone.kml</name>
    <Style id="PolyStyle00">
        <LabelStyle>
        <color>00000000</color>
        <scale>0</scale>
    </LabelStyle>
    <LineStyle>
        <color>ff0000ff</color>
    </LineStyle>
    <PolyStyle>
        <color>00f0f0f0</color>
    </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Folder>
    <name>justone</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Placemark id="ID_010161">
        <name>STUART CHARLES A JR</name>
        <Snippet maxLines="0"></Snippet>
        <description>""</description>
        <styleUrl>#PolyStyle00</styleUrl>
        <MultiGeometry>
            <Polygon>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            -78.941896,33.867893,0     -78.942514,33.868632,0 -78.94342899999999,33.869705,0 -78.943708,33.870083,0 -78.94466799999999,33.871142,0 -78.94511900000001,33.871639,0 -78.94541099999999,33.871776,0 -78.94635,33.872216,0 -78.94637899999999,33.872229,0 -78.94691400000001,33.87248,0 -78.94708300000001,33.87256,0 -78.94783700000001,33.872918,0 -78.947889,33.872942,0 -78.948655,33.873309,0 -78.949589,33.873756,0 -78.950164,33.87403,0 -78.9507,33.873432,0 -78.95077000000001,33.873384,0 -78.950867,33.873354,0 -78.95093199999999,33.873334,0 -78.952518,33.871631,0 -78.95400600000001,33.869583,0 -78.955254,33.867865,0 -78.954606,33.867499,0 -78.953833,33.867172,0 -78.952994,33.866809,0 -78.95272799999999,33.867129,0 -78.952139,33.866803,0 -78.95152299999999,33.86645,0 -78.95134299999999,33.866649,0 -78.95116400000001,33.866847,0 -78.949281,33.867363,0 -78.948936,33.866599,0 -78.94721699999999,33.866927,0 -78.941896,33.867893,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </MultiGeometry>
    </Placemark>
      </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

EDIT:
99.9% of the data I work with is in `*.shp` format, so I've just ignored this problem for the past week. But I'm going to get this process running on my desktop computer (off of my laptop) and run it until it either times out or finishes.

```
class ClassName

attr_reader :before, :after

def go
  @before = Time.now
  run_actual_code
  @after = Time.now
  puts "process took #{(@after - @before) seconds} to complete"
end

def run_actual_code
  ...
end

end
```

The above code should tell me how long it took. From that (if it does actually finish) we should be able to compute a rough rule of thumb for how long you should expect your (otherwise PERFECT) code to run without SAX parsing or "atomization" of the document's text components.

Comment: As @fotanus beat me to the nearly identical answer I will add my only additional 2 cents here: Also, have you looked at: https://github.com/schleyfox/ruby_kml

Comment: @Matthew: Isn't that for *generating* KML rather than *reading* KML?

Comment: I thought it did both - or at least I thought there was a ruby library that does and assumed this was it - looks like I might have been wrong on the second point.

Comment: I have checked out ruby_kml, it appears to be only for generating KML. The gem is excellent for dumping data into google earth to see what it looks like. I use Google Earth Pro as the "front end" for this application currently rather than using a web based map system. There isn't a ruby library for parsing KML presumably because its just XML. Besides, most KML files store their attributes in a CDATA area inside of the <description> tag and more likely than not its not uniform from kml to kml.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a huge XML file, you should not use default XML parser from Nokogiri, because it parses as DOM. A much better parsing strategy for large XML files is SAX. Luckly we are, [Nokogiri supports SAX](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/SAX/Document.html).

The downside is that using a SAX parser all logic should be done with callbacks. The idea is simple: The sax parser starts to read a file and let you know whenever it finds something interesting, for example a tag opening, a tag close, or a text. You will be able to bind callbacks to these events, and extract whatever you need.

Of course you don't want to use a SAX parser to load all file into the memory and work with it there - this is exactly what SAX want to avoid. You will need to do whatever you want with this file part-by-part.

So this is basically a rewrite your parsing with callbacks logic. To learn more about XML DOM vs SAX parsers, you might want to check [this FAQ from cs.nmsu.edu](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~epontell/courses/XML/material/xmlparsers.html#q1)

Comment: Honestly, because my current time is limited & because I don't know how to implement this xml scrape with callbacks, I'm going to just try to run this program as written and hope it works given enough day(s) to parse....any example code for the sax version would be appreciated, I have no experience with that (event-based?) style of programming whatsoever --- I'm just a RUBE-y guy :|

Comment: @boulder_ruby sorry, I lack the time to help you with real code - I only used SAX with C++, never with Nokogiri, and it is not trivial, but lightning-fast compared to DOM. An alternate solution would be break down your XML files in smaller parts. For example, if you  don't have nested Placemarks, you can try to read your file and build a lot of smaller valid XML files, each one with the placemark. Parsing lot of smaller files will be way faster than one huge file, because it avoids memory pagination on the queries.

Comment: I'm going to save the answer to this question until either I answer it or someone else does. Currently can't work on this coding assignment though and this is a definite road sign to the answer but its not **the** answer

Comment: @boulder_ruby anyway you like. If you can't make your SAX parser work, I suggest you to open another question showing your code.

Comment: haha ok, well, its a programmer's answer. And I appreciate it.

Comment: Unfortunately for the SO community, this is such an edge case that I currently can't justify spending several hours to solve it. At the rate I'm being compensated I'd do much better just to contact the city of Myrtle Beach, SC and pay $100 for their `.shp`-files, which is what 99.9% of my data looks like.

Comment: Haha I tell you what, I'll let my code process all night and if its not done in the morning I can rightly say that yours is the correct answer. Regardless, you'll be right from a programmer's perspective. But from an economist's perspective, where I could sleep while this was going on and pay only a few calories worth of currency to get the computation done...anyway. brb

Comment: @boulder_ruby sorry, I've been away for some time now. Thanks for selecting my answer. Good luck with the running time, hopefully it will work, but sometimes it just won't. I remember on my computer science course a teacher using an table with the solving times for matrix multiplication using two methods, and while for one input one of it worked in 10 hours, other is estimated to be completed after 2 bilion years. I hope you are in not such case.

Answer (score 1):

I actually ended up getting a copy of the data from a more accessible source, but I'm back here because I wanted to present a possible solution to the general problem. Less. Less was a built long time ago & is a part of unix by default in most cases.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29

Not related to the stylesheet language ("LESS"), less is a text *viewer* (cannot edit files, only read them) that does not load the entire document it is reading until you have scanned through the entire thing yourself. I.e., it loads the first "page", so to speak, and waits for you to call for the next one.

If a ruby script could somehow pipe "pages" of text into...oh wait....the XML structure wouldn't allow it due to the fact that it wouldn't have the closing delimeters from the end of the undigested text file......So what you would have to do is some custom work on the front end, cut out those first couple parent brackets so that you can pluck out the XML children one by one and have the last closing parent brackets break the script because the parser will think it is finished and come across another closing bracket I guess.

I haven't tried this and don't have anything to try it on. But if I did, I'd probably try piping n-lot blocks of text into ruby (or python, etc) via less or something similar to it. Perhaps something more primitive than less I'm not sure